Is it possible to speed up my set implementation?
I am trying to make a fast and space efficient set implementation for 64 bit unsigned ints.  I don't want to use set() as that converts everything into Python ints that use much more space than 8 bytes per int.  Here is my effort:
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

class HashSet:
    def __init__(self, capacity=1024):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.size = 0
        self.EMPTY = np.uint64(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)  # 2^64 - 1
        self.DELETED = np.uint64(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE)  # 2^64 - 2
        self.table = np.full(capacity, self.EMPTY)  # Initialize with a special value indicating empty

    def insert(self, key):
        if self.size >= self.capacity:
            raise RuntimeError("Hash table is full")
        if not self._insert(self.table, key, self.capacity, self.EMPTY, self.DELETED, self._hash):
            print(f"Key already exists: {key}")
        else:
            self.size += 1

    def contains(self, key):
        return self._contains(self.table, key, self.capacity, self.EMPTY, self.DELETED, self._hash)

    def remove(self, key):
        if self._remove(self.table, key, self.capacity, self.EMPTY, self.DELETED, self._hash):
            self.size -= 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    @staticmethod
    @njit
    def _hash(key, capacity):
        return key % capacity

    @staticmethod
    @njit
    def _insert(table, key, capacity, EMPTY, DELETED, hash_func):
        index = hash_func(key, capacity)
        while table[index] != EMPTY and table[index] != DELETED and table[index] != key:
            index = (index + 1) % capacity

        if table[index] == key:
            return False  # Key already exists

        table[index] = key
        return True

    @staticmethod
    @njit
    def _contains(table, key, capacity, EMPTY, DELETED, hash_func):
        index = hash_func(key, capacity)
        while table[index] != EMPTY:
            if table[index] == key:
                return True
            index = (index + 1) % capacity
        return False

    @staticmethod
    @njit
    def _remove(table, key, capacity, EMPTY, DELETED, hash_func):
        index = hash_func(key, capacity)
        while table[index] != EMPTY:
            if table[index] == key:
                table[index] = DELETED
                return True
            index = (index + 1) % capacity
        return False

I am using numba whereever I can to speed things up but it still isn't very fast. For example:
hash_set = HashSet(capacity=204800)
keys = np.random.randint(0, 2**64, size=100000, dtype=np.uint64)
def insert_and_remove(hash_set, key):
    hash_set.insert(np.uint64(key))
    hash_set.remove(key)
%timeit insert_and_remove(hash_set, keys[0])

This gives:
16.9 μs ± 407 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

The main cause is the code that I have failed to wrap with numba I think.
How can this be sped up?
EDIT
@ken suggested defining _hash as a global function outside the class. This speeds things up so now it is only ~50% slower than set().

You initialize the capacity to a power of 2. If you do that, you can avoid the costly modulo in key % capacity and replace it with key & (capacity - 1). On the other hand, many hash tables use capacities that are prime numbers since that avoids issues with common factors, e.g. if all keys are multiples of 2, 4, etc. Fibonacci hashing would also be an option

@Homer512 I tried that nice improvement but it didn't make a difference for the timing. It must be that the slower parts are elsewhere. I suspect it's in the parts that are not wrapped by numba.

[codereview.se] might be a better fit insofar as this is fairly open-ended (there's no such thing as a provably complete and canonical answer for a question where there's always room for a new data structure or algorithm to be suggested).

where is your time spent? spend some time profiling your code to see where to attack

Try instrumenting the code to see how many iterations the while loops take, maximum and on average

Numba is lazy with respect to jit-ing. Are the timings you give for the first timeit you did, or for second / third / fourth performance tests? The first run will also include the time it took to jit the function as well.

Quick profile on my machine shows this being approximately 20x slower than a python set. I think the performance is being dominated by having to make two functions calls from python, rather one (for the python set). Your implementation has to call your python helper function, which then calls the numba function. You might have better luck i you try to use a jitclass.

Just using numba.experimental.jitclass got the slow down to a more manageable 3x slower rather than 20x slower than a normal python set. Still not great though

numba role is not really to create fast very short atomic functions anyway. It is more in the spirit of numpy: it is efficient because you don't call it for a single operation, but for a "vectorized" bunch of operations. Otherwise, overhead of calling a C function from python (conversion of arguments, for example) isn't compensated by the speed up.

It would be more interesting to use numba here, if the idea was to provide a "vectorized" set. I mean a set in which you can insert a whole bunch of numbers in one call. And test for presence of a whole bunch of numbers in one call (with, if needed, several API: one that return True if one of the numbers passed is present. Anothe returning True iff all of those are present — so some lazy equivalence of any(x in S for x in array) and all(x in S for x in array). And yet another that use an array arg to return an array of same shape of booleans.

Those are just examples. They need to be usable, in your application, on lot of numbers, otherwise, they are useless. But point is, a numba function that just test if a number is at position x%m of an array (which is what you function does, when the set is not very populated) is probably not interesting. That is a too simple operation compared to the cost of the wrapping.

check out https://pypi.org/project/pyroaring/ (and other 'roaring' implementations

@MortenJensen I don't know how to profile it to tell.

@Dunes How exactly have you used jitclass? I get an error when I try to .

@ticktalk Thank you ! That uses about a third more RAM than my solution but it is almost as fast as set() which is really great.

@chrslg  I get the same slowdown relative to set() if I first insert a lot of keys and then do a query.   I need individual queries to be fast as I won't be doing them all in one bulk operation.

It seems that the main cause of this large overhead is that the jit function is given as an argument. If I change _hash to a global function (and remove the hash_func argument), it runs 8 times faster.

As requested, here is the class, but using jitclass. I'm not sure how much value all the type annotations add. I had been playing around to see if could get any improvements. Overall, your original code had peak performance of 20 μs. Whereas, the code below had a peak performance of 2.3 μs (an order of magnitude faster. However, using a python set was an order of magnitude faster again at 0.34 μs. These timings are only with the test harness you provided. No other performance testing was done.
The main things I had to do to get your code working with jitclass are:

Adding type annotations and a spec to the attributes of the class.
Casting the literal 1 to a numba.uint64. Without this, numba would promote the type of the expression to numba.float64, even when the local had a type annotation of uint64. Trying to index an array with a float caused the whole compilation step to fail.
Remove all njit decorators from methods on the class. jitclass automatically applies an njit to all methods. jitclass errors out if any of the classes methods have already been jit-ed.

The only bits you really need are:
# Extra arg to decorator tells numba what the dtype of the array is expected to be
@jitclass([('table', numba.uint64[:])])
class HashSet:
    capacity: numba.uint64
    size: numba.uint64
    table: np.ndarray

and
index = (index + numba.uint64(1)) % self.capacity

In addition I also made EMPTY and DELETED global constants. This gets you a small space saving if you have lots of small sets, but without any less in performance. With numba they truly are constants, and not just global variables.
Code
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba.experimental import jitclass

EMPTY = numba.uint64(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)  # 2^64 - 1
DELETED = numba.uint64(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE)  # 2^64 - 2


@jitclass([('table', numba.uint64[:])])
class HashSet:
    capacity: numba.uint64
    size: numba.uint64
    table: np.ndarray

    def __init__(self, capacity: int = 1024) -> None:
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.size = 0
        self.table = np.full(self.capacity, EMPTY) # Initialize with a special value indicating empty

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.size

    @staticmethod
    def _hash(key: numba.uint64, capacity: numba.uint64) -> numba.uint64:
        return key % capacity

    def insert(self, key: numba.uint64) -> bool:
        if self.size >= self.capacity:
            raise RuntimeError("Hash table is full")

        index = self._hash(key, self.capacity)
        while self.table[index] != EMPTY and self.table[index] != DELETED and self.table[index] != key:
            index = (index + numba.uint64(1)) % self.capacity

        if self.table[index] == key:
            return False  # Key already exists

        self.table[index] = key
        self.size += 1
        return True

    def contains(self, key: numba.uint64) -> bool:
        index = self._hash(key, self.capacity)
        while self.table[index] != EMPTY:
            if self.table[index] == key:
                return True
            index = (index + numba.uint64(1)) % self.capacity
        return False

    def remove(self, key: numba.uint64) -> bool:
        index = self._hash(key, self.capacity)
        while self.table[index] != EMPTY:
            if self.table[index] == key:
                self.table[index] = DELETED
                self.size -= 1
                return True
            index = (index + numba.uint64(1)) % self.capacity
        return False


Why do you think set is still so much faster?

Very little is being done in your performance test. There are no key collisions, and they key is inserted into the first slot that is found. So the only thing that can slowing it down is the overhead of calling the numba function. Presumably it has to type check all the arguments and pick the right function to dispatch based on types of the arguments.

A simple numba function that divides two numbers by two is much faster however. Maybe there is something we can do make it more like that speed?

That's not what I observe. I have python being twice as fast for lambda x, y: (x/2) + (y/2) vs the njit equivalent.

I get https://bpa.st/BH5A.  It's very very fast if the function isn't doing much. Do you see something different?
